# Personnalizing groupname in the treeview in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

Is it possible to personnalize the name of page/group in the tree view ?

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Right click the `group header` or `group footer` section in the gutter; choose 'Change group...'
- Select the 'Options' tab
- Check the 'Customize Group Name Field' option; either choose another field or enter a formula to do so